# Epson Workforce 645 no longer printing

Tags: printing

Using 16.04 OS with an Epson Workforce 645. When I set up 16.04 on this computer (new Dell Inspiron Desktop) back in 2016 and connected the printer everything ran fine. Currently no files will print.  The printer window shows a message "/usr/lib/cups/filter/commandtoepson" not available. No such file or directory.  I appear to have had a CUPS Printer configuration in the installed software; I since removed it and tried disconnecting, rebooting and reconnecting printer to see if it would install itself - no change. What can I do/try to get this printer operating again?

Also, I understood from U Help that there should be a Printer icon in the Systems Settings Hardware grouping.  I don't have such an icon.  Is the system missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the portal for linux drivers for Epson http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

entering 645 gives one this http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16859&DSCCHK=7ace3f4ac22dba2019b7bac02a046f33b413343b and with 64bit ubuntu you would need epson-inkjet-printer-201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb and are you happy to install a deb package?

to set up a printer you need 1) the drivers and 2) to register so this package covers 1) but Ubuntu should jump in and do 2) for you; if not, go to the PRINTERS folder and select the ADD NEW button and let it search

Comment: Thanks pdc.  I see the download for 645 but can you enlighten me on a "deb" file? The alternative appears to be an "rpm" file. Ubuntu set up as 64 bit. Any recommendation on which to use?

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying; a deb file is the Ubuntu format; if you click to download it, the system should offer to "open" it for you; if you accept that offer; open here means install; so it should be installed; if it doesn't offer to OPEN, then if you go to where it is downloaded to .. it should be the Downloads folder; then right-click on the icon and select INSTALL and it should all happen

Comment: Thanks, pdc. Felt a bit of a dummy re file types and looked it up on Google to find out!  I installed the add-on but the printer still didn't work and i got the same message - but - I didn't have CUPS installed and that was probably why. Subsequently, somehow, the add-on was removed. Next, I'll have to try to locate the CUPS program (I couldn't even find it in the software store when I last looked).  I'm from back in XT and AT days (80s/90s) and am on a new learning curve having been 'looked after' by IT dept and Windows, etc. for years; not any more so any tips appreciated.

Comment: I use a programme called Synaptic: it is core Ubuntu so fully trustworthy: I recommend you install it; if you type cups in its menu bar, you can then select to install it; and it will install whatever else is needed; you can delete stuff and it links to your update manager; I am fascinated how some installs seem not to install cups; it is so basic to me

Comment: pdc: Is that the Synaptic package manager I need to download first?  Sorry for the delay in responding but had other stuff occupying time.

Comment: yes; install synaptic if it is not already installed `sudo apt install synaptic` would work well from a terminal

Comment: pdc: found CUPS in the Ubuntu software when I searched this time and installed it. I now have a printer icon on the desktop. This shows that the Epson Workforce 645 is installed but there is an exclamation mark indicating a problem. I also installed the epson printer add-on file (see above): "....... amd64.deb". I tried printing an email but it didn't print and I got the same message as in the original message, above. The add-on deb file does not show in the Installed Software add-on section at the end of the list. I'll try installing the  deb file again when I'm back.